# Ruby mailgun batch doesnt set the recepient variables

Tags: ruby, mailgun

So here's the issue: I am trying to run a mass mailer using mailgun from a csv file

The file contains the email and a few parameters to replace in the html body (things like `"account_id", "first_name", "last_name"`)

Issue is that the placeholders (`"%account_id%"`) in the email do not get replaced by mailgun. the `recipient_variables` looks legit, but they don't show up on the mailgun server log

Code is taken from [here](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/docs/Messages.md) and [here](http://blog.mailgun.com/the-official-mailgun-ruby-sdk-is-here/)

I haven't tried constructing the message manually instead of a batch. Is this the gem issue or a mailgun api issue?

```
batch = Mailgun::BatchMessage.new(Mailgun::Client.new, Mailgun.domain)
batch.from(s[:from])
batch.reply_to(s[:reply_to])
batch.subject(s[:subject])
batch.body_html("<p>%account_id%</p>")

csv_data.each do |d|
  batch.add_recipient(:to, d[:email], d)   
end

puts batch.recipient_variables
batch.finalize
```